# How to handle receiving null value from bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-bundle

Hi I am passing a string to a fragment in a bundle and it can be null, but I am not sure how to accept null value when I read from the bundle argument

```
companion object {
    private const val KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM = "contact_p_num"
    fun newInstance(pNum: String?): GITFragment {
        return GetInTouchResponseFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleOf(KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM to phoneNumber)
        }
    }
}

val pNum = arguments?.getString(KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM) as String
```

When I read the KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM from arguments I get an error `Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String`

How can I accept null value when I am reading from arguments

Thanks
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `as String` part in the last line.

The [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/BaseBundle#getString(kotlin.String)) method returns a nullable string (`String?`). But `as String` tries to convert it to a non-null string, which causes the exception.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @dev.bmax, to handle the argument you can do these approaches:

```
//Do something when the argument has value
requireArguments().getString(KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM)?.let { phoneNumber ->

}

//Assign an empty string when the argument is null
requireArguments().getString(KEY_CONTACT_P_NUM) ?: ""
```